# Exercise 1.12 - Mark H. Holmes Introduction to Numerical Methods in Differential Equations

Tags: numerical-methods

I'd like to prove that the order of the two-steps Backward Differentiation Formula is $O(k^2)$. For this, I write
$$y'_i\approx \dfrac{y_{i}-{\tfrac {4}{3}}y_{i-1}+{\tfrac {1}{3}}y_{i-2}}{2k/3}=\dfrac{1}{k}\left(\dfrac{3}{2}-2E^{-1}+\dfrac{1}{2}E^{-2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{k}\left(\nabla+\dfrac{\nabla^2}{2}\right).$$

So, the approximation is
$$D= \dfrac{1}{k}\left(\nabla+\dfrac{\nabla^2}{2}+\dfrac{\nabla^3}{3}+\dfrac{\nabla^4}{4}+\cdots\right)\approx \dfrac{1}{k}\left(\nabla+\dfrac{\nabla^2}{2}\right)$$
and the error
$$ \dfrac{1}{k}\left(\dfrac{\nabla^3}{3}+\dfrac{\nabla^4}{4}+\cdots\right)$$

How could I proceed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The difference operator is usually denoted with the `\Delta` $\Delta$ symbol, not the gradient `\nabla` $\nabla$. /// You could be more explicit in writing that here $\Delta=1-E^{-1}$, and $E=e^{kD}$, so that $kD=-\ln(1-\Delta)=$ logarithm MacLarin-Taylor expansion. With all that, your approach is correct. You could, alternatively, also insert the exponential or Taylor shift series for $E^{-1}=e^{-kD}$ directly.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you! $\nabla$ is the backward difference, I forgot to say this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to notice that the higher powers of the difference operator come with a like power of $k$,
$$
\Delta^m=(1-e^{-kD})^m=(kD-\tfrac12(kD)^2+...)^m
=(kD)^m+\tfrac{m}2(kD)^{m+1}+...
\\~\text{or}~\\
[\Delta^my]_i= k^my^{(m)}(x_i)+O(k^{m+1}).
$$
This then implies that the remainder terms start with $O(k^2)$.